# Getting Active Window via Applescript throws error, "Can’t get window 1 of process"

Tags: macos, window, applescript

Script:

```
global frontApp, frontAppName, windowTitle

set windowTitle to ""
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
    set frontAppName to name of frontApp
    tell process frontAppName
        tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
            set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

return {frontAppName, windowTitle}
```

It works some times, but other times I get things like: `[2021-03-15 19:43:53.947] [error] Error: 339:344: execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of process "Adobe Premiere Pro 2020" whose value of attribute "AXMain" = true. Invalid index. (-1719)`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I get this error quite a lot from other apps, and my guess is that 1. the window sometimes is not yet ready when we try to reference it, not ideal but it can be quickly fixed by a delay. 2. The window mutates, for example in Safari, I get the error when I reference the window immediately after hitting a url, and once the page has completely loaded. Happens with terminal also when I run a command.

Comment: Unless you plan on using the variables you declared as `Global` , in other parts of your code or with other `script objects` etc, … `global frontApp, frontAppName, windowTitle` is not necessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following `repeat loop` added to your AppleScript code should do the trick

```
global frontApp, frontAppName, windowTitle

set windowTitle to ""
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
    set frontAppName to name of frontApp
    tell process frontAppName
        repeat until exists of ¬
            (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
            set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

return {frontAppName, windowTitle}
```